# Discord Js Prefix

Tags: discord.js

I use this command handler, and so far, the bot works great. But the problem is that it replies to every prefix. Like if my bot prefix is "!" then it responds to other prefixes too.

```js
client.on("message", async message => {

    if (!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (cmd.length === 0) return;

    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));

    if (command)
        command.run(client, message, args);

});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Try checking whether the message actually starts with `prefix` :)

Comment: `if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the message starts with the prefix. Add this at the top of the `.on(message)` event:

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
```

Should look like so:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; 
    if (!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (cmd.length === 0) return;

    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));

    if (command)
        command.run(client, message, args);

});
```